# Spring AMQP- How does i retry/re-queue message from DLX queue to original queue?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

i am trying to implement below scenario in my application

Exachange e1 -> Queue q1

DLX exchange e2 -> Queue q2

Also i have mentioned DLE and DLK in queue-q1 then message moving to queue-q2 on rejection/failure/timeout.

But how does i resend/retry message from queue-q2 to original queue-q1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that manually in your application after some analyze and filtering logic. Or you can make some `TTL` on that `queue-q2` to let not consumed messages to be expired. And you also need to specify in this queue a `x-dead-letter-exchange` as a name for the `Exachange e1` for desired recycling.

See more info yin this [article](https://gagnechris.wordpress.com/2015/09/19/easy-retries-with-rabbitmq/):

1. Create the dead letter exchange, which is just a normal exchange with a special name
2. Create a retry_message queue and have all messages published to the dead letter exchange route here
3. When you setup the retry_message queue, be sure to default the following parameter values of the queue
4. x-message-ttl: 30000 – This will set a ttl on any message published to the queue.  When the ttl expires, the message will be republished to the exchange specified in the `x-dead-letter-exchange` parameter.
5. x-dead-letter-exchange: original_exchange_name – This is where the message will get republished to once the message ttl expires.  We normally want this be the name of the exchange where the message was originally published.